# JVM using a LOT more than the max Heap

Tags: java, memory, jvm

We're having an issue with a JVM which is using a lot more than the max -Xmx.

We're using -Xmx2048 and it's currently using 17GB of OS memory.

I realise that the JVM can use use more than the max heap, but ours is using 15GB more which seems crazy.

The top dump looks like this:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                          
30477 root      20   0 22.683g 0.017t  18536 S   0.7 29.1  27:43.44 java -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128M  ....
```

(Note it's using 0.017TB or 17GB).

I've tried using jmap to debug:

```
sudo jmap -J-d64 -heap 30477

Attaching to process ID 30477, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 24.75-b04

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 8 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 0
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 100
   MaxHeapSize      = 2147483648 (2048.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 268435456 (256.0MB)
   G1HeapRegionSize = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 316145664 (301.5MB)
   used     = 150828136 (143.8409194946289MB)
   free     = 165317528 (157.6590805053711MB)
   47.708431009827166% used
From Space:
   capacity = 20447232 (19.5MB)
   used     = 3406624 (3.248809814453125MB)
   free     = 17040608 (16.251190185546875MB)
   16.660563151041668% used
To Space:
   capacity = 21495808 (20.5MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 21495808 (20.5MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 716177408 (683.0MB)
   used     = 516302952 (492.3848648071289MB)
   free     = 199874456 (190.6151351928711MB)
   72.09148825873044% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 56098816 (53.5MB)
   used     = 55842840 (53.255882263183594MB)
   free     = 255976 (0.24411773681640625MB)
   99.54370516482915% used

15065 interned Strings occupying 1516808 bytes.
```

And also...

```
sudo jmap -J-d64 -permstat 30477

Attaching to process ID 30477, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 24.75-b04
finding class loader instances ..done.
computing per loader stat ..done.
please wait.. computing liveness...liveness analysis may be inaccurate ...
class_loader    classes bytes   parent_loader   alive?  type

<bootstrap> 1908    11793728      null      live    <internal>
0x0000000780b97590  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b99b28  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b96cb0  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780113ca0  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b97c90  1   3048    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780114458  1   3048      null      dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b892b0  1   3024    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b989a8  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780019cf0  7731    44085000    0x0000000780019d40  live    sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader@0x0000000770239a20
0x0000000780113f10  1   3152    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780aa8918  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780114008  1   3040    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b7a8b8  1   3024    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780d236d0  1   3048    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780019d40  207 1327296   null      live    sun/misc/Launcher$ExtClassLoader@0x00000007701eb8b8
0x0000000780113e28  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x00000007801140b0  1   3064    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x000000078dc814f8  1   3024      null      dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b8abf8  1   3208    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b990a8  1   3048    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780114130  1   1904    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b98010  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x00000007801141b0  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780113620  27  86320   0x0000000780019cf0  live    org/apache/tapestry5/internal/plastic/PlasticClassLoader@0x000000077181b058
0x0000000780114418  1   3064    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b98d28  1   3048    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b89270  1   3024    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780113ed0  1   3024    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b97910  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b997a8  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b96930  1   3048    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780d36d38  1   3024    0x0000000780019d40  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b99ea8  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780bddff8  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780a63ca0  1   3024    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780114048  1   3048    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780113fc8  1   3024      null      dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780113de8  1   3072    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b7afb8  1   3040      null      dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780113e68  1   1904    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b7ac38  1   1880      null      dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780113d58  1   3064    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x00000007801140f0  1   3280    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b98628  1   3048    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x000000078088f900  0   0   0x0000000780019cf0  dead    java/util/ResourceBundle$RBClassLoader@0x00000007709cda40
0x0000000780b99428  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780d28ba0  1   3024    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b97030  1   3048    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780114170  1   3064    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x00000007801143d8  1   3048    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780114240  1   1880    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770
0x0000000780b8af60  1   3104    0x0000000780019cf0  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x0000000770059770

total = 53  9921    57418080        N/A     alive=4, dead=49        N/A
```

The app is a Play app which I know does weird things with classloaders, but I think the -permstat should account for that, so I'm stumped.

Any ideas?

John

Comment: Does the app, or any of its embedded libraries map files into memory? Cassandra for example is famous for doing this.

Comment: In addition to Chris's point, does your app invoke any native code via JNI?

Comment: Memory-mapped files are no issue because they just allocate address space, not RAM. So the indication may not be something to worry about.

Comment: Check `/proc/PID/smaps` for detailed information on the memory usage.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I wouldn't agree. Try mapping a large file and then touch every page of it - the pages would be loaded into physical memory.

Comment: @apangin in that case then other pages would be dropped, that is not necessarily a problem.. it might be, but then it may not too.  In this context I agree with Marko, a process that is reporting very high memory usage due to memory mapped files is usually not an issue.  But as you are alluding to, it is not clear cut because if it is under high mutation rates then it can become one.  For now the OP has not confirmed that we are looking at a memory mapped issue, so lets wait to see if this is a red herring or not.

Comment: WRT to JNI code... Certainly not in our code. In Play libraries, possibly, although this is a new issue for us.

I tried using pmap which reported that 22341732K was mapped... Not sure exactly how to interpret this. Would a dump help?

Comment: Besides mapped files and native libraries you might also want to look into DirectByteBuffer allocations (or anything that uses `sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory`), those are also outside the java heap

Comment: @ChrisK Yes, the way I currently understand it, the actual RAM pages used are sitting directly in the disk cache. So cache management takes care of it.

Comment: You guys are probably lucky to have never seen Java Heap swapping onto the disk due to excessive file mapping. In this case the arguments like "Cache management takes care" don't make it easier.

Comment: @John Have a look at `java.nio:type=BufferPool,name=direct` and `java.nio:type=BufferPool,name=mapped` MBeans (e.g. in JConsole) to see if the memory is taken by direct ByteBuffers. If this does not help show us the process' memory map.

Comment: As @Piotr says in his answer, you can't equate the Xmx value with the amount of used memory. Xmx is heap, and heap is just part of the JVM's memory usage.

Comment: Also, are you using Neo4J?

Comment: @apangin Let's not confuse disk I/O issues with RAM occupancy. Of course there will be disk traffic if you write to the whole file, but you won't get an OOME and the OS will not run out of available RAM either.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Due to disk I/O or not, large file mappings can make JVM unserviceable. Applications working with large MappedByteBuffers (e.g. Cassandra, ElasticSearch) are known to suffer from this unless using `mlockall` trick or something. That's why I argued against "Memory-mapped files are no issue" statement.

Comment: @apangin I don't contest that they *can* be an issue generally, but here we're discussing one *specific* issue---or, if you prefer, one specific aspect of the issue. The high number reported in the question does not directly indicate that it is a cause of a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So we figured this out, and it was just developer error. Thanks to all that suggested help.

I'm answering this anyway in case it helps anyone in the future.

The issue was simply not closing a stream open on a resource read using Class.getInputAsStream().

The confusion arose because the JVM heap usage was negligible, but each unclosed stream somehow left some native code allocated and not released.

Because there was no file handle leak (presumably because we're reading from the main JAR file each time, it was re-using the same handle), and because the JVM heap usage was tiny, we didn't spot it until we actually did a heap dump.

Anyway, the moral of the story is don't make the mistake I did which was assuming that if the JVM heap usage is low, there is no point looking at the heap dump, because in this case seeing the thousands of objects still allocated gave us a clue.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 6):

Note that Heap Area (bounded by Xmx) is only a part of the JVM process.

Basically memory occupied by the JVM is a sum of:

- Heap (bounded by Xmx)
- PermGen (in Java 7 and below, bounded by MaxPermSize)
- **Thread stacks: around 512KB - 1024KB per thread (depends on JVM and OS)**
- native buffers
- JVM code
- native data/code accessed via JNI

And possibly something more, you can find it by googling:)

So You have to check all those areas to ensure what is consuming memory.

I bet that you have simple thread leak - thousands of threads can eat up a lot of memory (as I said, assuming 1MB per thread, 10000 threads corresponds to 10GB of memory). You could simply make a thread dump (jstack -l  > dumpfile.txt) to see if it is an issue.

Of course it could be also external library that use native buffers or JNI, but it is less probable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Heap is limited to 2GB as I said - this is confirmed with jmap dump. 

Did a thread dump as suggested - only around 50 threads (well within normal usage).

PermGen seems OK from jmap dump (see above).

I will investigate the native buffers issue.